# How do I upload tables from Google Cloud storage in google big query

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to upload data from Google cloud storage into Bigquery, but it seems to throw an error as I run the query. What is it that I'm doing wrong here? Can someone please help!

Query:

```
 bq load test_table gs://ads-trial/4.csv userid:integer,
   usermobile:integer,status:integer
```

Error:

> Encountered " <ID> "bq "" at line 1, column 1. Was expecting: <EOF>

Comment: Can you post the first two lines of 4.csv?

Answer (score 0):

you have to specify the file format csv/json and datset name to which u want to upload the data .Try this
bq load --source_format=CSV datasetname.test_table gs://ads-trial/4.csv userid:integer, usermobile:integer,status:integer

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure I encountered this sometime. I would advise you to check the following -maybe obvious- things:

- Maybe, this error comes from forgetting to skip the header row, where
  the parser gets a string and expects an integer.
- Check if the delimiter really is a comma, and not maybe a semicolon or something like that.
- Another reason could be that the integers are actually between quotes due to Excel formatting or something like that.
- And maybe try it once from the Browser interface. http://bigquery.cloud.google.com

Like Fh. states, it could help if you posted the csv.